# How to loop through pages based on the maximum number available using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to loop through a GET Request based on the page count.

So I first hit this one endpoint which returns page_count=N(could be 1,2, or 10) and I'm able to extract the number using JSON Extractor and save it as a Variable but I am not sure how do I go about looping through page_count=(based on the total page_count I get from the preceding request).

Answer (score 2):

Just add a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set the number of loops to this `page_count` variable like

[image]

You can refer to the current page number inside the Loop Controller using `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) and [__intSum() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) combination like:

```
${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, appreciate that